# Control.Hide() vs Control.hidden=true

Tags: asp.net, ext.net

with a Server-sided call, which method is faster in hiding the Control?

```
Control.Hide();
```

or

```
Control.hidden = true;
```

Given the case we have something like:

```
<ext:Button runat="server">
   <DirectEvents>
      <Click OnEvent="hidethis"/>
   </DirectEvent>
</ext:Button>
```

and:

```
public void hidethis(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    var Control = sender;
    // above Choice
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try and measure?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz because the internal response time varies to much on my localhost:(

Comment: @Vogel612 Maybe that means it's just *insignificant*?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz it seemed to me, that .Hide() would have been slower, but i wanted to have external results. and as my colleagues' Laptops were as unable to produce helpful results as mine, i asked here... what's wrong with that again?

Comment: Hmm... "Too localized"?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz performance question. likewise applicable to other properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging into [Ext.Net Documentation](http://docs.ext.net/), I found :

> **Hidden Property** Render this component hidden (default is false). If true, the hide method will be called internally.

So calling `Hide()` is faster since the `Hidden` property calls the method `Hide()` anyway.

Comment: fyi, setting the `Hidden` property is _technically_ faster, but unless you are calling `Hide()` millions of times a second (that's a guess), you will not see a benefit. Use either.